# Laravel query join ManyToMany unique result

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 3 tables : artists, albums and artist_albums.

I want get 1 result per album. For example, the album "What a Time to Be Alive" have 2 artists : "Drake" and "Future".
I would like a result in the following form :

```
id: 1,
name: "What a Time to Be Alive"
artists: [
    name: "Drake",
    name: "Future"
]
```

Thanks for yous help

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set the Model up with a [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship, and [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the results.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific. Please set up a Many To Many relationship on the Album model.

```
class Album
{
    public function artists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Artist::class, 'artist_albums')
    }
}
```

Then, from the controller action, you can say:

```
return Album::select('id', 'name')
           ->with('artists:name')
           ->get();
```